# Calculate $I=\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2} dx$ with change of variable

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Let's try to calculate the integral $$I=\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2} dx, x>a>0$$ I think a suitable substitution would be $x=\dfrac{a}{\sin t}$. Then we would have $$dx=d\dfrac{a}{\sin t}=ad\frac{1}{\sin t}=ad\sin^{-1}t=-1a\sin^{-2}t\cos tdt=-\dfrac{a\cos t}{\sin^2 t}dt$$

Note that $$\sqrt{x^2-a^2}=\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{\sin^2 t}-a^2}=\sqrt\frac{a^2-a^2\sin^2 t}{\sin^2 t}=\sqrt\frac{a^2\cos^2 t}{\sin^2 t}=\dfrac{a\cos t}{\sin t}$$

Note that for the last simplification to be true we must have $0<t<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Can we actually conclude that, why (why not), as I cannot find a valid reason to do so?

Note that as $x$ and $a$ are both positive, then we must also have $\sin t>0$ as $x=\dfrac{a}{\sin t}$.

Maybe there are some specifics (that I'm not familiar with) in the formulation of the theorems for change of variables with integrals.  Thanks!

Comment: Why is $0 < t < \frac{\pi}{2}$ necessary? Also, you can write $\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin(t)}=\sec(t)$

Comment: You already have that $|x| \le |a|$, *n'est-ce pas*?  How does that relate to $t$?

Comment: Please don't write $\frac{1}{\sin t}$ as $\sin^{-1} t$ - that notation is reserved for the inverse sine function, the arcsine.

Comment: @XanderHenderson This question should be reopened.  There was no answer in the so-called "duplicate" question that addressed the question on how to handle the absolute value of the cotangent function.

Comment: @MarkViola, yep, I have no idea why it closed.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ can be negative, but the equation requires $|x|>a$

I would say $x = a\sec t$ rather than $x = a\csc = \frac {a}{\sin t}.$  The negative signs confuse me with the cosecant and cotangent functions.

$x = a\sec t\\
dx = a\sec t\cot t$

Yes, $-\frac {\pi}{2}<t<\frac {\pi}{2}$  I am not sure that that is particularly relevant.  Our substitution is a mapping from the real line excluding the interval $|x|<a$ to $(-\frac {\pi}{2}, \frac {\pi}{2})$ but nothing has been left out.

$\int \sqrt {a^2 (\sec^2 t - 1)} a\sec t\tan t\ dt\\
\int a^2 \sqrt{\tan^2 t}\sec t\tan t\ dt$

If we are going to be precise about this. $\sqrt{\tan^2 t} = |\tan t|$ rather than just $\tan t$ that is the radical always returns the principal root.

But, I will work with $a^2 \int \sec t\tan^2 t\ dt$ with a note that should we be working with negative values of $x$ and $\tan t$ this is going to flip the sign of the entire integral.

This integral is not obvious, but here is the trick.

Integration by parts:

$u = \tan t, dv = \sec t\tan t\\
du = \sec^2 t, v = \sec t$

$a^2 (\sec t\tan t - \int \sec^3 t\ dt)\\
a^2\sec t\tan t - a^2\int \sec t(\tan^2 t + 1)\ dt\\
a^2\sec t\tan t - a^2\int \sec t\ dt - a^2\int \sec t\tan^2 t\ dt$

But $a^2\int \sec t\tan^2 t\ dt = I$

$I = a^2\sec t\tan t - a^2\int \sec t\ dt - I\\
I = \frac {a^2\sec t\tan t - a^2\ln |\sec t + \tan t|}{2} + C$

Revisit our note that when $\tan t$ is less than zero, the sign flips.

$t< 0$ implies

$I = \frac {-a^2\sec t\tan t + a^2\ln |\sec t + \tan t|}{2} + C\\
\frac {a^2\sec t(-\tan t) - a^2\ln |\frac {1}{\sec t + \tan t}|}{2} + C\\
\frac {a^2\sec t(-\tan t) - a^2\ln |\frac {\sec t - \tan t}{\sec^2 t - \tan^2 t}|}{2} + C\\
\frac {a^2\sec t(-\tan t) - a^2\ln |\sec t +(-\tan t)|}{2} + C$

If we have $-\tan t$ factors/terms when $t<0$ and $\tan t$ when $t\ge 0$ then that is $|\tan t|$

$I = \frac {a^2\sec t|\tan t| - a^2\ln |\sec t + |\tan t||}{2} + C$

Reverse the substitution.
$\sec t = \frac {x}{a}\\
|\tan t| = \sqrt{\frac {x^2}{a^2} - 1} = \frac {\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}{a}$

$\frac {x\sqrt {x^2-a^2} - a^2\ln |x + \sqrt {x^2- a^2}|}{2} + C$